# Working Copy not accessible anymore. How to change password?

Tags: svn, cornerstone

I am using cornerstone for working with SVN on my Mac. I have several Working Copies checked out for which the SVN password recently changed.

Now I get the following error, if I try to update the working copies:

```
Description : You are not authorized to access the files in the repository.
 Suggestion : You might be required to provide a user name and password when prompted before being allowed to access the repository.

Technical Information
=====================

      Error : V4AuthorizationError
  Exception : ZSVNAuthorizationException

Causal Information
==================

Description : Server sent unexpected return value (401 Authorization Required) in response to OPTIONS request for 
...
     Status : 175002
       File : subversion/libsvn_ra_neon/util.c, 563
```

How can I change the password for these working copies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password has to be changed in the Repositories section for the appropriate Repository and a restart of cornerstone is necessary, so the changes become effective.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

Right clik in the white place -->Tortoise svn -->Settings -->Saved data and then clear the authentication data.

Good luck!

Comment: I am using cornerstone (not Tortoise), though. see above.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that you have to change your credentials in the Repositories section, but not obvious how to do that.  Instructions: Control-click on the repository name.  This brings up a menu.  Choose "Edit Repository..."  from the menu.  This brings up a form with repository information that you can edit and then save.  For example, my server uses http, so I edit the "HTTP Server" portion of the form.